# Apache server does not recognize the htdocs folder

Tags: php, apache, htdocs

I have installed Apache server correctly and I have downloaded php thread safe from php official website.

I start apache service and create a (phpinfo.php) file which contains the following code:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

I copy the following file to the directory "Apache\htdocs\" and try to access the following file through the browser with the address "localhost/phpinfo.php". But I get 404 file not found error.

if I try to access "localhost" I get a single text "It Works" but nothing more.
I deleted all the files in the htdocs directory but I still get "It Workds" text when I try to navigate "localhost".

Why is it happening? how can I create a .php file and browse it through the browser?

Note that:
1- Apache service is started.
2- I have add the following code to the end of the "apache\conf\httpd.conf" file:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "C:/php5/"
LoadModule php5_module "C:/php5/php5apache2_4.dll"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: search your system for index.html and put your files in that directory

Comment: There are lots of that file now ! All inside the "Manual" directory which are useless

Comment: There was a file named "Index.html" in "apache/htdocs/" but I deleted it.

Comment: but you still get the "It Works!" page? \

Comment: yes. I know that's odd.

Comment: Must be the wrong directory

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was since I had changed the listening port of my apache server I did not wrote it when I was trying to access the pages in the "apache/htdocs" directory.

Now all I have to do is to add the port number when I want to access a page through the browser:

```
http://localhost:8085/Index.html
```

Its working...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you installed version 2.2 the default document root should be:

> C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs

If you're using MAMP or some similar package please update your question to reflect that.

Comment: Default document root is "C:/Apache/htdocs". but it seems Apache does not recognize it at all thats I deleted Index.html file from the mentioned directory but I still get "It Works" message when I try to access "http://localhost" from the browser